# Segmentation fault when accessing a pointer's member function in a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

For some reason I'm getting a segmentation fault; I'm using a vector of pointers, which point to a class object. Basically I need a node that has a vector of pointers to other nodes, in other to make a multigraph. Here's the relevant part of my code:

**node.h:**

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

class node
{
public:
    string content()
    vector<node*> next;      //causing the error
    void add_arc(node a);

    string rna_frag;

#endif
```

**node.cpp:**

```
void node::add_arc(node a)
{
    node *b = &a;    //b->content() works fine here
    next.push_back(b);
}

string node::content()
{
    return rna_frag;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
int main()
{
    vector<node> nodes;
    node a;
    node b;
    node c;

    a.add_arc(b);
    a.add_arc(c);
    a.rna_string = "G";

    nodes.push_back(a);
    nodes.push_back(b);
    nodes.push_back(c);

    cout << nodes[0].content() << endl;    //prints "G", works fine
    cout << nodes[0].next.size() << endl;  // prints "2", works fine
    cout << nodes[0].next[0]->content() << endl;  //segmentation fault
    //cout << nodes[0].next->content() << endl;   //also segmentation fault
    //cout << nodes[0].next[0]->rna_frag << endl; //also segmentation fault
}
```

in this case, nodes[0]'s string is "G" and is pointing to 2 other nodes, so the first 2 couts are working perfectly. But when I access the vector's contents it just crashes and gives a segmentation fault error. Anyone know why?

Comment: _"Here's the relevant part of my code"_ No, post a [MCVE]. You should know by now that you are expected to do that.

Comment: if you do `vector.push_back(a)` the node in the vector is a copy (stored at a different memory adress). Moreoever your `add_arc` takes its parameter by value and the node you push into the vector is local to that function. Once this you leave the scope of this function dereferencing that pointer is undefined

Comment: @tobi303: Why are you answering the question in the comments section? There's a lovely answer section down below for you to use!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit from an answer I would expect a bit more, but actually you are right...

Comment: @tobi303: The problem is that if you were wrong (you're not) there would be no way to downvote your answer. It wouldn't go into review queues. It couldn't be edited. Comments, with their limited functionality and no peer review mechanism, are only for requesting clarification and having flame wars.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thats some really good points that I actually never considered. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @tobi303: No problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `add_arc` you are storing the address of the parameter `a`, which is then destroyed when the function exits - so you have undefined behaviour.

You're also copying nodes when you call `nodes.push_back()`, which is going to cause you a lot of grief.

You are going to need to either stop copying or write a proper copy constructor (and then follow the rule of 3, or 5).

Comment: Ahh thank you, I forgot to make 'a' a reference, I'll take your advice about copying

Answer (score 2):

With

```
void node::add_arc(node a)
{
    vertex *b = &a;    //b->content() works fine here
    next.push_back(b);
}
```

you add in `next` the pointer to an object that is destroyed exiting from the method (`a`).

Using it...

```
cout << nodes[0].next[0]->content() << endl;
```

crash!

Suggestion: transform `next` in a vector of nodes (not pointer of nodes)

Answer (score 2):

If you do vector.push_back(a) the node in the vector is a copy (stored at a different memory adress). Moreoever your add_arc takes its parameter by value and the node you push into the vector is local to that function. Once this you leave the scope of this function dereferencing that pointer is undefined behaviour.

You should consider passing the argument by reference, or in that case even simpler a pointer to the node you want to add. However, also then you have to be aware that in your main this...

```
vector<node> nodes;
node a;
node b;

a.add_arc(b);

nodes.push_back(a);
nodes.push_back(b);
```

would not be what you want, because now `a` has `b` added as arc, while the second entry of the nodes vector is a **copy** of `b`. Maybe in that case it would be easier to use a `vector<node*> nodes` because you can copy pointers and they will still point to the same object.