# Copy constructor for a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm trying to create a node class that contains a vector of  pointers. Here's my code:

**node.h:**

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

class node
{
public:
    vector<node*> next;
    void add_arc(node & a)

    string some_string;

#endif
```

**node.cpp:**

```
void node::add_arc(node & a)
{
    node *b = &a;
    next.push_back(b);       //only copyies nodes
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
int main()
{
    vector<node> nodes;
    node a;
    node b;
    node c;

    a.somestring = "a";
    b.somestring = "b";
    c.somestring = "c";



    a.add_arc(b);      //a should point to b
    a.add_arc(c);      //a should point to c

    nodes.push_back(a);
    nodes.push_back(b);
    nodes.push_back(c);

    cout << nodes[0].next.size() << endl;           // prints "2", works fine
    cout << nodes[0].next[0]->some_string << endl;  //empty
}
```

I thought it would be as easy as just overloading push_back:

```
void push_back(vertex * pointer)
{
    next.push_back(pointer);
}
```

But I think I really need a copy constructor, or some other method to make this work. How would I go about doing this for a vector of pointers?

Edit: I guess I didn't explain it well. Look at the answers in this question:
[Segmentation fault when accessing a pointer's member function in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091616/segmentation-fault-when-accessing-a-pointers-member-function-in-a-vector)
Making 'a' a reference did not work for me

Comment: Read chapter two smart pointers

Comment: Why should a contiguous containter store nodes? And why should `next` be `std::vector<Node*>`?

Comment: `cout << nodes[0].next[0]->some_string << endl;  //empty` well you haven't set the string to any value in this code, so it's empty

Comment: The problem is the parameter in add_arc is being destroyed, the strings end up being empty even with a reference. Are smart pointers really the best way? Also @milleniumbug I editted the string to have values, they still end up empty

Comment: I can't see any reason for this to fail, and indeed [it works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0f09c5d06717373) (if I turn your code into a [MCVE] and fix the syntax errors).

Comment: See the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091616/segmentation-fault-when-accessing-a-pointers-member-function-in-a-vector  They describe exactly what's happening

Comment: @xyz - *The problem is the parameter in add_arc is being destroyed*  -- They are being destroyed because your client code must have destroyed them (and the code would be different than what you posted).  The precondition that you must have is that if you give my code a reference, that reference better be "alive" when my linked list code wants to access it.  You broke that promise somewhere in the calling code.  As LightnessRacesInOrbit pointed out, the example works because those references being passed aren't being killed.

Comment: The question you linked and this one are not the same.  The question you linked passes something by value and this one passes by reference.  IE add_arc destroys nothing in this question.

Comment: I've just entered your exmaple into VS2015 and the output is: 2 \n b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It works...

Your code generates as expected the correct output (see [online demo](http://ideone.com/15cgKn)):

```
2
b
```

### ...However this design is not future proof

However this result is related somehow to luck, because in your code snippet:

- the nodes in the `nodes` vector are copies of the original object including all their pointers
- the local objects a, b, c to which these pointers point still exist

However in more complex code, you'd quickly end up with dangling pointers. 
Imagine:

- Bad example 1: you create a graph, keeping all the nodes directly in a vector of nodes. You then add the first arcs between the nodes.  As soon as you'll add a new node to the vector, reallocation might occur and you'd risk to see all your `next` pointers invalidated.
- Bad example 2:  you initialise a graph like you did, but in a function called by `main`.  In this case, as soon as you return from this function, all the local nodes get destroyed and the vector's node will point to objects that do no longer exist.  UB guaranteed !

### How to improve ?

Your design fails to recognize that the nodes all belong to the same graph.

There is a quick and dirty way out:  always create the node from the free store, and store them in a `vector<node*>`.

```
vector<node*> nodes;
node *a = new node("a");  // Imagine a node constructor 
node *b = new node("b");
a->add_arc(b);            //change signature, to accept a pointer 
nodes.push_back(a);
nodes.push_back(b);
```

There's a **better** approach: improve further the previous approach, but use `shared_ptr<node*>`  to make sure that nodes that are no longer referenced (neither by a vector of nodes, nor by an arc) are destroyed automatically.

There's an even better approach:  encapsulate the nodes in a class representing a graph.  In this case, you could consider using a `vector<nodes>` and replace the pointers in `next`, by indexes of the target nodes in the vector.  No pointer, but perfect copy of graphs will be much easier.  And no more memory management hassle.

```
class node    // just to give the general idea
{
public:
    vector<int> next;  // not usable without the graph 
    void add_arc(int a)
    string id;
};

class graph {
    vector<node> nodes; 
public:  
    void add_node (node a);  
    void add_arc (string from, string to);  
    node& operator[] (size_t i); 
    ...
};
```